# G-zip compression needs to be more than 90%

Tags: php, .htaccess, server, compression, gzip

I am quickly looking for your guidance to increase the limit of my gzip compression.

Right now when i check the gzip it shown me that the compressed content size is 80% and we want to achieve 90%.

Can any one help me to achieve the 90% gzip compression.

link is : dmm.magicrete.in

and the testing url is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7x0Sp8mD9X3N1NGOUJxNWdzMTA/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: if you just want the "90%" without regards of its meaning: just add a few thousand spaces to the uncompressed data. otherwise: *80% just is the ratio your data can be compressed to!* maybe you could force your server to compress more thoroughly for another one or two percent, but at the cost of one second processing per page view or something like that. oh, and don't freak out if you test a JPG: they're already compressed, so the gzip will most probably even *in*flate it. that's just the way compression works.

Comment: Thank you Franz, but how can i add few thousand spaces to uncompressed data ? Means you would like to tell me to increase the image sizes or sizes of the page ?

Comment: yes. because that **is** the only way to arbitrarily increase your compression ratio: add useless, but good compressable data to your input. which was meant sarcastically to show you that you *problem* is not a problem. the 80% you get is **just how compression works**.

Comment: Franz, Then it will be like how more you serve more you get !! right ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/)'s `-11` compression level, which uses [zopfli](https://github.com/google/zopfli) to take much more time and memory to eke out a little more compression than gzip's `-9` level.

However that is unlikely to get you from 80% to 90%, which would require reducing the size of the compressed data by a factor of two.

Beyond that, you would have to try other compression methods, like [xz](http://tukaani.org/xz/). Though I kind of doubt that even `xz` will get you a factor of two.